# Contours of percentiles on level plot

Tags: r

How can we estimate the level contours that correspond to what percentage of points lie inside the contour?

This post describes how to add contours to a scatterplot in R:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay

For example:

```
    x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1.3)
    y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1);
    dens <- kde2d(x, y, n=200); ## estimate the z counts
    plot(x, y);
    contour(dens, nlevels = 5, add=T)
```

So instead of the 5 levels drawn in the above example, I would like levels that correspond to 99%, 95%, 50%, etc of points lie inside a contour line.

Thanks...

Comment: Is this a geometric question at heart, concerned with finding *connected closed* contours containing a given percent, or are you just asking for the [`ecdf` function](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/ecdf): the empirical cumulative distribution (and its inverse)?

Comment: Just the ecdf, @whuber.

Comment: Okay.  This question has been flagged as marginally off-topic and, given that you know exactly what you want and you're just looking for an `R` solution, SO looks like the right place for it.

Comment: take a look at the logic in `HPDregionplot`, in the `emdbook` package.

Comment: @BenBolker does my answer seem correct below?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (snippet from `HPDregionplot` from @benbolker)?:

```
library(MASS)
x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1.3)
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1);
dens <- kde2d(x, y, n=200); ## estimate the z counts

prob <- c(.98, .95, .90, .8, .5, .1)
dx <- diff(dens$x[1:2])
dy <- diff(dens$y[1:2])
sz <- sort(dens$z)
c1 <- cumsum(sz) * dx * dy
levels <- sapply(prob, function(x) {
    approx(c1, sz, xout = 1 - x)$y
})

plot(x,y)
contour(dens, levels=levels, labels=prob, add=T)
```

Comment: (1) you need `library("MASS")` to make this work (for `kde2d`); (2) you might want to might want to specify `labels=prob` in your `contour()` call.